# Enlarge ImageView within ListView with animation onClick

Tags: android, listview, animation, imageview

I am trying to implement an enlarge animation like it is in WhatsApp. I have a ListView where I have an ImageView at the left of each ListView item. A click on the ImageView should enlarge the image and show it in the middle (almost full screen width).

I tried [the Android developer guide suggestion](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) but it did not work for me. So I googled a little bit but could not find "the perfect answer". Here is what I got so far.

```
private void enlargeProfilePicture(View view, Drawable drawable, View convertView) {
    fullScreenImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(
            0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    scale.setDuration(1000);

    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    convertView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    rootView.getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    Animation translate
            = new TranslateAnimation(startBounds.left,
            finalBounds.left,
            startBounds.top,
            finalBounds.top);
    translate.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator());
    translate.setDuration(1000);
    // Animation set to join both scaling and moving
    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);
    animSet.addAnimation(scale);
    animSet.addAnimation(translate);
    // Launching animation set
    animSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            fullScreenImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    fullScreenImageView.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

So root is the container in which my ListView is defined, fullScreenImageView is the ImageView which is showing the Drawable in its enlarged way, convertView is the view inside the ListView (the ListView item itself) and view is the ImageView clicked on.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_size_profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So basically what is going wrong is the translation. How can I find the right starting and ending coordinates for the translation? The scaling animation is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I fixed the issue. The problem was with how I used the animation constructors. I do not know where I got the code from but I just used it from somewhere else it obviously was working but not for my case. Here is one working example.

```
private void enlargeProfilePicture(View view, Drawable drawable) {
    // view is the ImageView holding the image inside one ListView item
    fullScreenImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
    scale.setDuration(1000);
    scale.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    rootView.getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    Animation translate
            = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, startBounds.left + view.getWidth()/2,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, finalBounds.left,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, startBounds.top - view.getHeight()/2,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, finalBounds.top);
    translate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    translate.setDuration(1000);
    // Animation set to join both scaling and moving
    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);
    animSet.addAnimation(scale);
    animSet.addAnimation(translate);
    // Launching animation set
    animSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            fullScreenImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    fullScreenImageView.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

Comment: What's this drawable & rootView?? What's the value for drawable?

Comment: "So root is the container in which my ListView is defined, fullScreenImageView is the ImageView which is showing the Drawable in its enlarged way, convertView is the view inside the ListView (the ListView item itself) and view is the ImageView clicked on."
The drawable is the picture you want to show. It probably will be the same as the preview image you have in your list view item (or maybe you use a low quality picture for the preview and a high quality picture for the enlarged one, up to you).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Animator` rather than `Animation`.

```
Animator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_X, 2f);
Animator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_Y, 2f);
AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
animSet.setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animSet.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
animSet.start();
```

`Animator` is better than `Animation`, because it modifies the view's properties. `Animation` just modifies the appearance, but not the view itself.

Use that code if your app's minSdk is higher or equal to 14.
If your app requires at least sdk 11 use this one:

```
Animator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 2f);
Animator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 2f);
```

Comment: How do I add the Animators to the AnimatorSet ? So there is no need for a translation to "get the little ImageView to the center of the screen during scaling" ?

Comment: animSet.playTogether or animSet.playSequentially (excuse me, I modified the example). In your case I'd use playTogether

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The ImageView cannot get "out of the ListView item". It is just scaling up like before.

Comment: Ok, that code does not solve the problem (it is just an advice on which class to use). You cannot solve the problem just translating the image, remember that the ImageView's parent is always the ListView! You have different solutions: load the same image in full_size_profile_picture and apply the animation; change the ImageView's parent a runtime (from the ListView to the RelativeLayout and viceversa (I don't like it, it may cause other problems)); read the Authentic Motion section on http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html and follow that guide